# Inner join without column and without using pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following query, I have three `cte` that will always display one row each.

Is there a simple way where I can display each value horizontally without having to `group by weeknum` for the `inner join`?

I also prefer not using the `pivot` operator or anything else that makes a simple query unnecessarily complex.

```
;with cteSales as
(
    select count(*) as 'Total' from sales where weeknum = 33
),
cteVendors as
(
    select count(*) as 'vendors' from Vendors where weeknum = 33
),
cteClients as
(
    select count(*) as 'clients' from Clients where weeknum = 33
)
select total, vendors, clients from
cteSales inner join cteVendors on ??
inner join cteClients on ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use 3 subqueries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.sales WHERE weeknum = 33) AS Total,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Vendors WHERE weeknum = 33) AS Vendors,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Clients WHERE weeknum = 33) AS Clients;
```

If you have to use CTEs, use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
--; is a statement TERMINATOR, it goes at the end of ALL your statements,
-- not statement that require the previous statement to be properly terminated.
WITH cteSales AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
     FROM sales
     WHERE weeknum = 33),
cteVendors AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS vendors
     FROM Vendors
     WHERE weeknum = 33),
cteClients AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS clients
     FROM Clients
     WHERE weeknum = 33)
SELECT S.Total,
       V.vendors,
       C.clients
FROM cteSales S
     CROSS JOIN cteVendors V
     CROSS JOIN cteClients C;
```

Comment: Well... that was easy. Thanks,

Comment: If it answers the question, @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf , please mark it as the solution so that future users know the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I tried as soon as you answered, but SO forces me to wait 10 minutes before marking an answer as a solution.